# My screen resolution changed overnight and I can't seem to change it

Tags: nvidia, graphics, display, display-resolution, ubuntu-studio

I recently installed Ubuntu Studio.  It worked fine the other night, then I shut down my PC and went to bed.  When I booted it up the next day, the resolution was stuck at 640x480 and it won't give me any options for aspect ratio or refresh rate.

I ran xrandr and got this message:

> xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
>   Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
>   default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
>      640x480       73.00*

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 on an HP Z400 workstation.  My monitor is quite old, a Samsung 932BW LCD monitor with a native resolution of 1440x900 and a refresh rate of 75hz, an aspect ratio of 16:10, with a contrast ratio of 1000.1/3000.1 (dynamic).

I don't know if it makes a difference, but it's VGA1 hookup is running through a Display Port converter into my PC.  It worked fine last night, I don't know what happened, and this tiny resolution has basically rendered the OS unusable for the purposes I need (audio/video editing).  Please help, I'm a total n00b.

Update:  I reinstalled Ubuntu Studio and things worked fine.  Then it asked me if I wanted to install software updates.  I did so and then restarted the workstation and now the resolution problem has cropped up again, so it's something to do with one of those updates.

Comment: I don't know, but I'd boot up a 'live' system and see if it was the same (ie. your install media will do using the 'try ubuntu-studio'). Next I'd check your cables are connected correctly, and not loose.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, the HP Z40 workstation doesn't have a graphic card? Display and the workstation should have a DVI port, why don't you connect them directly?

Comment: The Z400 was a gift from a friend, and it came with some modifications.  Among them a graphics card which I'm guessing only has Display Ports, and then two converters that seem hard attached to the display ports, one which converts to VGA1 and the other which converts to HDMI.

Comment: I did a booted live from the usb drive and the resolution was fine.  The connections seem solid too.  I guess I'll try reinstalling Ubuntu and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Ok, so it looks fine from the live boot and it looks fine after reinstallation.  But once I installed the new software updates that were available since 19.10 was first released and restarted the workstation, the resolution problem crops up again.  So it has something to do with one of the updates.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve (for me) 
Open applications menu and go to Settings -> Additional Drivers -> select xserver-xorg-video-nouveau -> apply -> reboot